# Docker registry cannot delete images?

Tags: docker, curl, docker-registry

I have deploy a docker registry on my instance, after push images to the registry successfully, I want to perform a delete opearation with `curl -XDelete`, following the document on docker site, "`DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>`", but the response show not success:

Response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>`
```

Does anyone met such problem?

Comment: Delete extra slash after V2. I believe that is the problem. something like this ```curl -v -X DELETE http://xxx/v2/xx/xx/manifests/latest```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong spelling, actually, I'm using the correct url:  
curl -XDELETE localhost:5000/v2/hello2/manifests/<Reference>

Reference is the sha256 of my image

Comment: By default the delete image is disabled. You need to allow in your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a redirection and `curl` is involve, try at least to instruct `curl` to follow said redirection:

```
curl -L -XDELETE localhost:5000/v2/hello2/manifests/<Reference> 
     ^^
```